# What is ExtendedSocket exception and how can I fix it?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, xamarin, client

I am getting an error whenever I try to send data to a server in c# using System.Net.Sockets and Xamarin. I am only getting this error when sending data but not connecting. The error message is 
    "Exception thrown: 
    'System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory.ExtendedSocketException' in 
    System.Net.Sockets.dll"
I am not sure how to fix this but here is my connection code running when a button is pressed.

```
        Label label = this.FindByName<Label>("label");
        Socket sock;

        string ipI = "127.0.0.1";
        int portI = 6419;

        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipI);

        IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, portI);

        sock = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sock.Connect(remoteEndPoint);
        byte[] sData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(num);
        sock.Send(sData);
        label.Text = "Added 1 to server";
        sock.Dispose();
```

Comment: Add the exception AND stacktrace to your question

Comment: You are using `127.0.0.1` for your server but that would be the device/emulator and not your self-hosted server.

Answer (score -1):

instead of websocket try using tcpclient:

```
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(127.0.0.1, 6419);

            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = await ns.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead);

            client.Close();
            return result;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
```